# Apply value to a jquery generated input field

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

my TD's are generated by grid object on a fly
i'm trying to change value of the fist ***empty*** input that is positioned inside :

```
$("#get_isrc").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'xtras/isrc.php',
        success: function(data){
            $("#new_isrc").val(data);
            $("#get_isrc").val('Apply');
            $("#get_isrc").addClass('apply');
        }               
    }).error(function(){
        alert('Error');
    });
});


$(".apply").live("click", function(){
    var s = $("td[col=ISRC] input").val();
    if (s === "") { 
        $(this).val(($("#new_isrc").val()));
    } 
});
```

html - static:

```
<h3>Generate next ISRC</h3>
    <input id="new_isrc" type="text" />
    <input id="get_isrc" type="button" value="Get next ISRC" />
```

html generated by jquery:

```
<tr id="4"><td><input class="editableInput" type="text" /></td><td col="ISRC" class="editableCell"><input class="editableInput " type="text"></td></tr>
<tr id="1"><td><input class="editableInput" type="text" /></td><td col="ISRC" class="editableCell"><input class="editableInput " type="text"></td></tr>
<tr id="2"><td><input class="editableInput" type="text" /></td><td col="ISRC" class="editableCell"><input class="editableInput " type="text"></td></tr>
<tr id="3"><td><input class="editableInput" type="text" /></td><td col="ISRC" class="editableCell"><input class="editableInput " type="text"></td></tr>
```

tr's 1 and 2 have ISRC values from database, tr 3 is empty, but positioned last

tr 4 - is newly added empty line and i want a generated isrc applied to it...
code i provided above doesn't work. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `.val()` into an array of inputs, do this:

```
$("td[col=ISRC] input").each(function() {
    // each iteration function
    var s = $(this).val();
    if (s === "") { 
        $(this).val(($("#new_isrc").val()));
        return false; // stops each iteration
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

If you want to add the same value to all inputs, do this:

```
$("td[col=ISRC] input").each(function() {
    var s = $(this).val();
    if (s === "") { 
        $(this).val(($("#new_isrc").val()));
    }
});
```

If you want to add dynamic values to all inputs, do this:

```
$("td[col=ISRC] input").each(function() {
    var s = $(this).val();
    if (s === "") { 
        $(this).val(getNextValue());
    }
});
function getNextValue() {
    // your business implementation here
}
```

Comment: i was thinking adding each() to my code! yes this did work, thank you. the only problem - if i have several new lines - this will add to each of them?...